# Alternativa correta que implementa um validador para um campo data no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, validação, data

a.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'data_nascimento' => 'regex:ddmmyyyy',
]);
```

b.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'data_nascimento' => 'required|date',
]);
```

c.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'data_nascimento' => 'digits:8|integer',
]);
```

d.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'data_nascimento' => 'datetime|null',
]);
```

Estou entre A e B, preciso de ajuda.

Comment: `regex:ddmmyyyy` está incorreto.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que essa seja a melhor, a sua data que vem da tela está no formato Brasileiro, ou seja, **dia**, **mês** e **ano**, utilize [date_format com o formato d/m/Y](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-date-format):

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'data_nascimento' => 'required|date_format:"d/m/Y"',
]);
```

<sub>***Referencia***: [date_format:format](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-date-format)</sub>

Comment: Obrigado pela informação.

Comment: @PedroSoares a sua data está no formato brasileiro? como está o formato?

Comment: Sim, formato brasileiro.

Comment: @PedroSoares se for a resposta da sua, pergunta assinale como resposta!